# Regex to detect word abbreviations

Tags: php, regex

I'm currently working on a CSV that has information about Portugal's administrative areas and postal codes, but the file doesn't follow any strict format, which means sometimes there are entire strings in uppercase, along with other issues.

The issue I want to solve is as follows : some areas have a abbreviation at the end of the name, related to it's parent's administrative level, that I want to remove. As far as I can see, this are the rules :

1. Abbreviations don't take more than 3 characters in lenght (always 3 characters so far);
2. The first character may be any letter, case insensitive;
3. The last 2 characters are always consonants (e.g. Z, B, M, P, ..);
4. **(edit)** the abbreviations always occur as the last word in a string;

**(edit 2)** - The strings are always `UTF-8`

The purpose is to remove this abbreviations from the area names.

Comment: what about the "too many TLAs" problem? is `foo` a valid word, or an acronym? which acronym?

Comment: if there's a occurrence of 3 characters at the end of a name, that follow the rules mentioned, it is an abbreviation. I've checked it by "hand".

Comment: @yoda And it's always the last thing on a line?

Comment: @MarcB Both `tla` and `foo` have vowels in the last two character spots, so they wouldn't be affected. Just making that clear, FTR ;) We can discuss this further later; IRC FTW.

Comment: @yoda You should update your question to contain that information, as "*always the last thing in the line*" can greatly improve accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds simple enough..

```
/\b[a-z][ZBMP]{2}\b/i
```

Would match any such described abbrevations, Add letters to the second character class (`[ZBMP]`) to complete the match.

It would only match if it's not part of another word (That's the `\b`'s job).

Comment: It's matching words with more than 3 characters. If I split the last word out and apply that expression, it works, but it doesn't do the job alone.

Comment: @yoda: It works for me. What string are you testing it against?

Comment: It broke with this string : `Urrô Arc`. It might have to do with special characters. By the way, the strings are encoded with `UTF-8`.

Comment: Apparently `ô` is considered to be a word boundry :P Hold on